# how does kyverno handle cleanup for generated resources

Tags: kubernetes

Let's say I have a rule in kyverno cluster policy to generate configmap. Now at some point of time in future I remove that rule from cluster policy(cluster policy still exists). Is kyverno capable of garbage collecting the configmap?

Cluster Policy with two generate rules(r1 and r2):

```html
apiVersion: kyverno.io/v1
kind: ClusterPolicy
metadata:
  name: cp1
spec:
  rules:
  - name: r1
    match:
      resources:
        kinds:
        - Namespace
        selector:
          matchLabels:
            test: "true"
    generate:
      synchronize: true
      kind: ConfigMap
      name: cm1
      namespace: "{{request.object.metadata.name}}"
      data:
        kind: ConfigMap
        data:
          # Enter all your target logging info below
          test.yml: |-
            cm1
  - name: r2
    match:
      resources:
        kinds:
        - Namespace
        selector:
          matchLabels:
            test: "true"
    generate:
      synchronize: true
      kind: ConfigMap
      name: cm2
      namespace: "{{request.object.metadata.name}}"
      data:
        kind: ConfigMap
        data:
          # Enter all your target logging info below
          test.yml: |-
            cm2
```

Once applied if you remove one of the generate rules and apply policy again it does not remove config map.

Comment: What is your ConfigMap configuration?  In general yes, after few tests with removing ConfigMap rule, it looks like Kyverno is capable of its garbage collecting, when setting `excludeUsername` flag as per [docs](https://kyverno.io/docs/installation/#configmap-flags).

Comment: @anarxz I'm on kyverno 2.2.0 and removing rules does not remove configmap for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `generate` rule which uses a `data` declaration (not a `clone` one) with `synchronize: false`, deleting of the rule will cause deletion of the downstream resource(s). We currently have a bug impacting this, but it's supposed to work this way.